# How can I know if jasper reports is evaluating the summary band?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have report footer with page number and a confidential disclaimer. I need to hide confidential disclaimer in summary pages but need page number as it is.

I have added `isSummaryNewPage="true" and isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true"` to the report.

Is there any flag to check whether the page is summary page or detail page inside `<printWhenExpression> </printWhenExpression>` or `<textFieldExpression> </textFieldExpression>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AFIK** There is no built in property that tells you that you are on summary band.

However, I think this is a case where you safely can use what I call the "parameter hack" solution if summary band is on multiple page or for any another reason you don't like to use the `lastPageFooter` band.

## The parameter hack solution

1. Add a parameter that is a [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (you can also use `List`, `Map` or other similar classes). Instance it with an empty `HashSet`.

   ```
   <parameter name="paramHack" class="java.util.Set">
       <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.HashSet()]]> </defaultValueExpression>
   </parameter>
   ```
2. In a textField (in your case first on summary band), add a key to it in `printWhenExpression`, be careful the expression can be evaluated more then one time so always make sure it returns true.

   ```
   <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{paramHack}.add("summary") || true]]></printWhenExpression>
   ```
3. You can now use `$P{paramHack}.contains("summary")` to know if the textField has been evaluated, hence in case to know if we have arrived to summary band and not print the "confidential disclaimer".

   ```
   <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{paramHack}.contains("summary")]]></printWhenExpression>
   ```

#### Example

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="WhenSummary" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryNewPage="true" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" uuid="bbec9a5c-d9fc-4e29-b2b0-cea6d7a50394">
    <parameter name="paramHack" class="java.util.Set">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.HashSet()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="40">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="545" height="40" uuid="74f6c3de-9867-4895-b7bb-c9cdb124fbdc"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[First just an empty page]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="50" y="0" width="440" height="40" uuid="af5f6f4c-fe77-4f07-a080-035230123f50">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{paramHack}.contains("summary")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Confidential"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="493" y="0" width="60" height="40" uuid="78b7b8bd-4189-42ea-8120-5a09a8b5701c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="22"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="545" height="40" uuid="9ee45216-e7e1-4e5a-bbed-1f057ade1967">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{paramHack}.add("summary") || true]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Summary page]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: result]

---

If you also like to use this solution for summary `pageHeader` (that starts before summary, but after detail band) you can for example add a "fake" group and in the group footer band (that is evaluated after detail band, but before page header on summary band) add another property to our `paramHack` parameter `detail_end`.

```
<group name="FakeGroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA["dummy"]]></groupExpression>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="1">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="553" height="1" uuid="373fc74e-011a-4f03-9cd4-9d5d9464ab06">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{paramHack}.add("detail_end") && false]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Hidden used just to know when detail band ends"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
```

> Note: I have used another name, since this will be set before `pageFooter` on last detail band page, hence you can't use same name of flag for both `pageFooter` and `pageHeader`. To clarify on last detail band page in `pageFooter` the `$P{paramHack}.contains("detail_end")` is `true` but `$P{paramHack}.contains("summary")` is `false`.

Then in page header use this other flag to determine if to show or not show content.

Comment: It worked for footer, but technique is not working for header content. Please help.I have multiple page summary. First page it is showing the content and the rest it is hidden.

Comment: @Yogeendra I have updated post, you use a similar method but with a new flag, on way is to use a fake group, the groupFooter band will be evaluated before pageHeader on summary band, but note you need **another flag** (hence another name), since it is evaluated before page footer on last detail band page ;)